# Create intentional duplicate records in RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm aiming to create blank questions, which are then assigned to editors to create.

To do this, I'm trying to create a form where I input the topic and the # of questions, and then have the backend iterate on that # to create x intentionally duplicate questions.

Controller:

```
def create
   @question = []
   5.times do
    @question = Question.new(question_params)
   end
  end
```

Params:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"unfqSHnfdNhidUCvLf3Zck8MeP59Qobe2bJz0tUhWQ1SUh29a8LdoGAYpUwbOOJS8U+wzlDQVBXQYcKeRqLDmQ==", "question"=>{"name"=>"four", "topic_id"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Save "}
```

The above ideation only creates one record, I think because the controller is iterating, but only has one set of params input from the form.

Am I approaching this all wrong?

**EDIT**
Full working controller for posterity, thx to the answer below.

```
controller do
def create
  if @question = 5.times.each_with_object([]) do |_, to_return|
    to_return << Question.create(question_params)
    end
    redirect_to admin_questions_path, notice: "Questions created"
  else
   # Handle failure
   redirect_to admin_questions_path, notice: "Questions NOT created"
  end
end
```

Comment: You have `new`. Where is `save`?

Comment: Also you’re overwriting the `@question` Array with each loop. What you want is something like `@question << Question.create(question_params)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something more like:

```
def create
  5.times.each_with_object([]) do |_, to_return|
    to_return << Question.create(question_params)
  end
end
```

That will return an `array` with five `@question` records all using the same `question_params`.